# Regarding odoo and flask server installations?

Tags: python, api, server, odoo

I have installed the odoo9 server with workers, and also runs the flask server both are needs the werkzeug server, but the odoo9 werkzeug version is = 0.9.6 and flak needs 1.1.X version. while doing this need to uninstall the odoo werkzeug and installed the 0.9 version, can we run the flask also in the same werkzeug version(0.9.6 )not the 1.12

I follows these commands
pip uninstall Werkzeug

sudo pip install Werkzeug==0.9.6

SERVER RESTART

pip install -U flask-cors

FLASK SERVER RESTART

Answer (score 0):

in python you could prepare different environments according to the needs of the application using `virtualenv` or the new one `pyenv`.
`pyenv` gives the ability to run different python versions as well. so you could have python 2 for odoo & python 3 for flask.

Comment: cannot we run the flask also in python 2? means to run the same line in both

Comment: yes you can, if your flask version support python 2.

Comment: i am not able run those in parally and installed in globally

Comment: install pyenv and its plugin virtualenv.